# Can't tell why collection fold and reduce aren't equivalent

Tags: kotlin, collections, reduce, fold

I am going through the Kotlin Koans course. And I am [in the fold section](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Collections/Fold/Task.kt).

GIVEN

```
data class Shop(val name: String, val customers: List<Customer>)

data class Customer(val name: String, val city: City, val orders: List<Order>) {
    override fun toString() = "$name from ${city.name}"
}

data class Order(val products: List<Product>, val isDelivered: Boolean)

data class Product(val name: String, val price: Double) {
    override fun toString() = "'$name' for $price"
}

data class City(val name: String) {
    override fun toString() = name
}
```

and

```
fun Shop.getOrderedProducts(): Set<Product> =
    customers.flatMap(Customer::orders).flatMap(Order::products).toSet()
```

The question asks me to do the following:  Return the set of products that were ordered by all customers. Here is my answer, which for whatever reason is not accepted (**would you point the error?**)

```
// Return the set of products that were ordered by all customers
fun Shop.getProductsOrderedByAll(): Set<Product> =
    customers.flatMap(Customer::orders)
        .map(Order::products)
        .reduce{ acc, el -> (acc.intersect(el)).toList()}
        .toSet()
```

Here is the correct answer:

```
// Return the set of products that were ordered by all customers
fun Shop.getProductsOrderedByAll(): Set<Product> {
    val allProducts = customers.flatMap { it.getOrderedProducts() }.toSet()
    return customers.fold(allProducts, { orderedByAll, customer ->
        orderedByAll.intersect(customer.getOrderedProducts())
    })
}
```

While I don't dispute their answer -- I can follow it without problem -- I don't see why mine isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I was assuming that each customer is equivalent to one order, but that's not the case. Each customer may place multiple orders. And the question is to intersect products per customer -- not product per order

Comment: May be you should accept own answer as correct, because this question is shown in search as waiting to answer. Or, are you waiting for other answers?